# Meaning of the word "govern" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from an article. Here it is:

> What US law **governs** the sanctions on China?

Comment: The link doesn't work, by the way.

Comment: What was confusing about the definitions you found when you consulted several good dictionaries?

Comment: Now I understand that I was confused by the grammar

Comment: Which part of it was confusing to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite obvious that there are many laws in the United States of America (that's why they are called US laws), but the question is exactly which one is **responsible for** (or **regulates** the process of) the imposition of economic and other sanctions on the country of China? What law in the US do you need to use in order to impose sanctions on China? That's what it's saying.

See [meaning 1.1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/govern) for the verb *govern* in the Oxford English Dictionary:

> 1.1 Control, influence, or regulate (a person, action, or course of events)
>
> *‘the future of Jamaica will be governed by geography not history’*